# Some use for additional partitions?

Tags: partitioning

Earlier I had windows and Ubuntu 16.04 on my system with 1 TB HDD.
For more that 1 year I didn't use Windows so I removed it recently.

I have given 50gb for `/` and 300gb for `/home` . Around 300 gb of NTFS data. The remaining approx 350GB in not in use. What all partitions can I make to use that in Ubuntu or should I keep it as it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is up to you but I would myself do this:

1. / 25 Gb. Should be more than enough for a desktop.
2. /home/ 10-25 Gb. And don't use it (just keep settings in there (or the hidden files))
3. remainder: a named partition (/discworld is mine).

   - I myself have 1. and 2. on a SSD and 3. is a 1Tb disk.

---

Move all directories in /home to /discworld and edit ./config/user-dirs.dir to point to /discworld. Put a copy of the file in /discword/

- When you need to reinstall format / and /home/, mount /discworld and copy the user-dirs file over to ./config.
- When you want to keep settings in /home you can format / and mount both /home and /discworld. All you then need to do is install the additional software you need and those will pick up your settings files.
- a backup consist of making a copy of /discworld

---

It is not a good idea to keep NTFS when you do not have windows. Problems with the partition are best fixed using Windows. You can use gparted to convert it into EXT. Or move the files and then delete the NTFS and enlarge your /discworld.

Comment: I do programming in C++ and Ruby. Also I am planning to start learning linux file system development. Is it logical to create a partition for programming related tasks.

Comment: Sure. But you can also use /discworld for that. Like put the workplace from Aptana to a sub-dir there. You can also consider to put /opt on  an partition (that one can be used to install 3rd party software like eclipse) Than when reinstalling just mount /opt and copy the services over manually to get these active again